# links in html - colours

Tags: html, css

i have this in my code

```
a:link {text-decoration: none; color: black;}
a:visited {text-decoration: none; color: black}
a:active {text-decoration: none; color: black}
a:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: grey;}
```

but now i need which in the same page, but in another local, the colors change to another

for exemple in the header the link colors are white and in the button are black.

I can't simple repeat the code above.

How can i solve that?

Comment: AFAIK you will need to repeat the code and include the new colour references. Unfortunately CSS doesn't allow variables and constants etc so it's a case of repeating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign a class to the header links:

`<a class="header" href="yourpage.html">Header Link</a>`

and then in your CSS:

```
a.header:link {text-decoration: none; color: black;}
a.header:visited {text-decoration: none; color: black}
a.header:active {text-decoration: none; color: black}
a.header:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: grey;}
```

and for the non header links:

`<a href="link.html">Normal Link</a>`

and then for the normal links in your CSS:

```
a:link {text-decoration: brown; color: black;}
a:visited {text-decoration: none; color: black}
a:active {text-decoration: none; color: black}
a:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: grey;}
```

Comment: another alternative is change a to another thing. I tested now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your after variables and constants in css you could always try [lesscss](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) if your using Rails.

Comment: I did not know less, it is very impressive. +1